# How to export multiple versions of metrics with OpenTelemetry Prometheus exporter in dotnet?

Tags: .net, prometheus, versioning, metrics, open-telemetry

I’m currently integrating OpenTelemetry into a dotnet project and I’m using the Prometheus exporter for exposing my metrics on the /v1/metrics path. Given that this project is currently under development, we foresee major changes in the metrics that this system provides. We are looking for a way to export different versions of metrics on different endpoint paths simultaneously, such as /v2/metrics, /v3/metrics, etc.

This is the part of code in question:

```cs
    services.AddOpenTelemetry()
        .WithMetrics(opts => opts
            .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("rrfc"))
            .AddMeter(TelemetryUnit.CALL_TELEMETRY_METER)
            .AddPrometheusExporter(opt =>
            {
                opt.ScrapeEndpointPath = "/v1/metrics";
            }));
    
    app.UseOpenTelemetryPrometheusScrapingEndpoint();
```

Is there a way to configure multiple Prometheus exporters with different ScrapeEndpointPath options and use them in the same project? Or is there another approach to achieve this goal? Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**What I have already tried:**

I have tried adding a second prometheus exporter with a different scraping endpoint but the last one will always be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you observed, the last exporter configured will win. The [doc comments](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/66a606229e57d25e2b80a856b9634e9f8f241737/src/OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting/OpenTelemetryBuilder.cs#L75) on `WithMetrics` reads:

> Note: This is safe to be called multiple times and by library authors.
> Each registered configuration action will be applied sequentially.

Instead of using the extension methods you would need to manually instantiate two separate `MetricProvider`s, and scrape endpoints like so:

```cs
var meterProvider1 = Sdk.CreateMeterProviderBuilder()
    .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("rrfc"))
    .AddMeter(TelemetryUnit.CALL_TELEMETRY_METER)
    .AddPrometheusExporter("v1 metrics", opt =>
    {
        opt.ScrapeEndpointPath = "/v1/metrics";
    }, name: "v1 metrics");

var meterProvider2 = Sdk.CreateMeterProviderBuilder()
    .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("rrfc"))
    .AddMeter(TelemetryUnit.CALL_TELEMETRY_METER)
    .AddPrometheusExporter("v2 metrics", opt =>
    {
        opt.ScrapeEndpointPath = "/v2/metrics";
    });

app.UseOpenTelemetryPrometheusScrapingEndpoint(meterProvider1, null, null, null, "v1 metrics");
app.UseOpenTelemetryPrometheusScrapingEndpoint(meterProvider2, null, null, null, "v2 metrics");
```

[Looking at the implementation](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/f468dd8359f38e883782c9478e7bf7d65e2b866a/src/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Prometheus.AspNetCore/PrometheusExporterApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs#L123), passing `null` to the path parameter will cause a lookup against the exporter options to retrieve the configured exporter path when using named options.

Manually making multiple instances of `MeterProvider` means figuring out how to manage their lifecycle. The `WithMetrics` extension method does this by hooking in to the .NET dependency injection framework.

Per the [doc comments](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry/Sdk.cs#L82) on `CreateMeterProviderBuilder` state:

> Creates a `MeterProviderBuilder` which is used to build
> a `MeterProvider`. In a typical application, a single
> `MeterProvider` is created at application startup and disposed
> at application shutdown. It is important to ensure that the provider is not
> disposed too early.

A quick solution is registering both `MeterProvider` instances as singletons, like so:

```cs
services.AddSingleton(meterProvider1);
services.AddSingleton(meterProvider2);
```

This should properly dispose of both instances when the application is terminated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Matt! I tried to implement the solution you provided the only part that i seem to struggle with is  this part

`app.UseOpenTelemetryPrometheusScrapingEndpoint(meterProvider1);`

There doesn't seem to be an overload of this function that only accepts a variable of type MeterProviderBuilder.
I would really apprecite it if you could further explain this part of the solution to me.

Comment: no worries I think I got it to work. I was able to setup two different endpoints for prometheus to scrape with different metrics. as for my aforementioned problem this is how I changed that line for it to finally work:
`app.UseOpenTelemetryPrometheusScrapingEndpoint(_meterProvider1.Build(), null, "/v1/metrics", null, null);
app.UseOpenTelemetryPrometheusScrapingEndpoint(_meterProvider2.Build(), null, "/v2/metrics", null, null);`
I wonder if there is a way to get the path from meterprovider so that i wouldn't have to set the path statically.